# When sending the picture, how did Jesse know Walt put his money in a black barrel?

Tags: plot-explanation, breaking-bad

In the last season of ***Breaking Bad***, Jesse has an idea on how to fool Walt and find where he hides his money, to help out Hank catches him. Jesse sends a picture to Walt showing money in the exact same black barrel Walt actually used...

Now how in the world did Jesse know Walt put his money in black barrels and especially that exact same barrel? The only people who knew about the black barrels and saw them were Saul and his two employees (the fat black man and the redhead). I don't see any reason why they would share that specific information with Jesse at any point in the story.

Answer (score 9):

[From the BB wikia](http://breakingbad.wikia.com/wiki/To%27hajiilee):

> Hank Schrader and Steven Gomez meet after the failed sting and discuss
>   options. Hank says that Jesse has a plan to get Walter, but Gomez
>   doubts Jesse is able to come up with something useful. They approach
>   him in the car, **Jesse tells them that they need solid evidence of
>   Walt's criminal activities, but Walt got rid of any possible evidence
>   linked to him, except for one thing: his money.** If they can find the
>   money, there is nowhere for Walt to run. **Gomez asks if Jesse knows
>   where the money may be, Jesse answers that he doesn't -- but there is
>   someone who may know.** At the Schrader home, Gomez brings a piece of
>   some or other animal brain and some information: **Huell Babineaux has
>   been taken into witness protection to be interrogated about the money.**
>   Gomez is worried that maybe the guy will call for a lawyer, but Hank
>   believes that he won't, under the circumstances. Hank throws the brain
>   on the ground and says that it's Jesse's turn.
>
> At the DEA safe house, Huell sits on the couch as Hank and Gomez come
>   in to question him about the money. **Hank fakes that Walt is getting
>   rid of anyone connected to the poisoning of a boy named Brock Cantillo
>   and Huell is on the hit list.** He also lies that Patrick Kuby has been
>   missing for some time, but **Huell doesn't belive that Saul Goodman
>   would simply allow Walt to take people out like this. Hank then shows
>   a fake picture of Jesse dead on the floor with his brains blown out**,
>   which causes Huell to panic and say that he doesn't have any intel
>   about Walt's actions. **Hank asks about the money, Huell reveals that he
>   and Kuby did collect the money for Walt, they put it inside seven
>   barrels and took them inside a van to Walt.** Later, Walt returned with
>   a dirty van and without the barrels. Walt took a shovel from the van
>   and left as he and Kuby cleaned the van and returned it to the rental
>   agency. Hank and Gomez now have information from Huell on which van it
>   was and where it was rented. The two agents leave, with Hank giving a
>   final warning to Huell not to use his cellphone in any way and not to
>   leave the house for his own safety.

Comment: In short, Huell had seen the barrels and could have easily described them to Hank.